# cometD does not work in incognito mode

Tags: lightning-web-components, cometd

this is my code

```
    renderedCallback() {
        console.log('render');
        if(!this.isUserGuest) {
            getSessionId()
            .then(result => {
                this.sessionId = result;
                this.error = undefined;
                loadScript(this, cometdlwc)
                .then(() => {
                    if(!this.libInitialized) this.initializecometd('/data/History__ChangeEvent');
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
            })
        }
        else {
            console.log('Guest user');
        }
    }

 initializecometd(channel) {
 this.libInitialized = true;

 //inintializing cometD object/class
 var cometdlib = new window.org.cometd.CometD();
 cometdlib.configure({
                url: window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname + '/cometd/47.0/',
                requestHeaders: { Authorization: 'OAuth ' + this.sessionId},
                appendMessageTypeToURL : false,
                logLevel: 'debug'
             });
cometdlib.websocketEnabled = false;
cometdlib.handshake(function(status) {
    if (status.successful) {
        console.log('Successfully connected to server');
        cometdlib.subscribe(channel, response => {
            /// main hook
            console.log('--- inside action');
            console.log(response);
        })

    } else {
        /// Cannot handshake with the server, alert user.
        console.error('Error in handshaking: ' + JSON.stringify(status));
     }
   });
  }
```

but if i run my chrome in incognito mode i don't recevie payloads although connection is established succesfully. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

CometD does work in Chrome Incognito or Firefox Private windows.

You probably have some other error going on.

You have already turned on CometD debug logging, so I recommend that you look at the browser console for the logs, there should be an error that explains why your application does not work.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no debug messages in console except Console.log('Successfully connected to server');